# The usage of adv + can

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, adverbs, word-order

Some People say **can only** have same meaning as **only can**, and some not. So I want to make it clear.

> I only can get it.

Does the sentence mean: I am the the only one who can get it?

So, how do I understand **totally can**?

e.g.

> I totally can get it.

what the difference is between **totally can** and **can totally**?

e.g.

> I totally can put it in.

> I can totally put it in.

Comment: "I only can get it" doesn't sound idiomatic to me as a native UK speaker. "I totally can get it" is slangy/colloquial (as a form of emphasis that you definitely are able to do it) but in informal contexts it's OK.

Comment: So, how do you understand **I only can get it** then, it's not sound idiomatic to you though. And an another question: as an alternative, what sentence should I use to replace it with a equivalent sentence? Say, how should I briefly represent that **I am the only one can get it**.

Comment: Nobody says "I only can get it." It's just too awkward. If you want to sound egotistical, then you'd say "Only I can get it" or "I alone can understand it."

Comment: @FeliniusRex-gone ***Only I can get it*** could mean "Only I can collect the key from the  agent, because I'm the only one whose ID the office holds".

Comment: totally is slang as used there.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "I only can get it" is awkward precisely because it's incredibly ambiguous as to what it means. *Does* it mean that you're the only one who can get it, or that you *only* get it (as opposed to having fully mastered it)? It doesn't really mean one or the other, so people steer clear of that sentence structure.

"Totally" in the contexts you have used it in is a colloquial term, where "totally" means "definitely" in a confident sort of way. In this case, both "totally can" and "can totally" work equally well and mean the same thing, though people seem to use the form "totally can" more often.

Comment: I think **totally** modifies **can** in **totally can put it in**, and **totally** modifies **put** in **can totally put it in** . Due to **totally** modifying different object, I speculate they should be some different

Comment: Uh, I’m telling you, they’re not. You’re thinking of “totally” as an adverb; it’s a colloquial term that functions as “definitely” or “surely.” Hopefully you can see that in this context, whether you’re “modifying” either “can” or “put” actually doesn’t affect meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic usage:

Only I can get it. [that is, you can't understand it. Don't have the ability to.]

In ***modern American colloquial usage***, **totally** is used like this:

a) I **totally** get it. That means: *I understand it completely*.

b) I can **totally** get it. That means: I have the ability to understand it completely.
c) **An alternative** but less likely way to say that is to put *totally* before the *can*: I **totally** can get it. This is the same as the previous one.

Comment: ***Totally*** in this example is known as an "intensifier". It has nothing to do with "total" - it is simply adding emphasis to the assertion.

Comment: @WS2 If you reread my answer, there is no hint that it has anything at all to do with the word total in its usual sense. totally just means completely.

Answer (score 0):

> I totally can get it.

We don't say this, it's unclear what you mean.

> I totally can put it in.

> I can totally put it in.

We can say these.  "Totally" is *emphatic* - it emphasizes your ability to "put it in" here, and expresses that you have *no doubts* about your ability to do so.

Both of these are OK and mean the same thing. But it is informal, so avoid it in business or other formal communication.

For formal communication, use "certainly" instead.  Just as with "totally", either word order is acceptable:

**I certainly can put it in.**

**I can certainly put it in.**

Both are OK.